# What exactly NSURLLocalizedNameKey resource returns and is it different from the url's last path component?

Tags: objective-c, nsurl

`NSURL` provides a method `getResourceValue:forKey:error:`. One of the possible keys is the `NSURLLocalizedNameKey` which from [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurllocalizednamekey?language=objc) returns:

> The resource’s localized or extension-hidden name, returned as an NSString object (read-only).

What does it mean "localized or extension-hidden name"?
Is it different from just calling `[url lastPathComponent]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `localized` means you get for example ***Desktop*** on an English system, ***Schreibtisch*** in German or ***デスクトップ*** in Japanese.
- `extension-hidden` considers the checkbox in a Finder Info window like

  [image]

`lastPathComponent` returns always the internal non-localized full file/folder name.